# Inheritance person class not working

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I've made an inheritance class with base class Person

Person.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Person 
{
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Person &p);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream &is, Person &p);
private:
    char* m_name;
    int m_age;
    string m_ssn;
protected:
    virtual void Read(istream &is);
    virtual void Write(ostream &os) const;
public:
    Person();
    Person(const char* const name, int age, const string &ssn);
    Person(const Person &p);
    ~Person();
    Person & operator = (const Person& other);
    virtual string getName() const;
    virtual int getAge() const;
    virtual string getSSN() const;
    void setName(const char* const name);
    void setAge(int age);
    void setSSN(string ssn);
    string getType() const;
};
```

Person.cpp

```css
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Person.h"

using namespace std;

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Person &p)
{
 p.Write(os);
 return os;
}

istream& operator>>(istream &is, Person &p)
{
 p.Read(is);
 return is;
}

Person::Person()
{
 m_name = new char[10];

 for (int i = 0; i < 10-1; i++)
 {
  m_name[i] = 'X';
 }
 m_name[10 - 1] = '\0';

 m_age = 0;
 m_ssn = "XXX-XX-XXXX";
}

Person::Person(const char* name, int age, const string &ssn)
{
 m_name = new char[(int)strlen(name)+1];

 for (int y = 0; y < (int)strlen(name); y++)
  m_name[y] = name[y];
 m_age = age;
 m_ssn = ssn;
}

Person::Person(const Person& P)
{
 m_name = new char[(int)strlen(P.m_name)+1];

 for (size_t i = 0; i <= (int)strlen(P.m_name); i++)
 {
  m_name[i] = P.m_name[i];
 }
 m_age = P.m_age;
 m_ssn = P.m_ssn;
}

Person::~Person()
{
 delete[] m_name;
}

Person& Person::operator=(const Person& other)
{
 if (this == &other)
  return *this;
 delete [] m_name;

 m_name = new char[(int)strlen(other.m_name) + 1];
 for (int i = 0; i <= (int)strlen(other.m_name); i++)
 {
  m_name[i] = other.m_name[i];
 }

 m_age = other.m_age;
 m_ssn = other.m_ssn;
}

string Person::getName() const
{
 return string(m_name);
}

int Person::getAge() const
{
 return int(m_age);
}

string Person::getSSN() const
{
 return string(m_ssn);
}

void Person::setName(const char* const name)
{
 delete[] m_name;
 m_name = new char[(int)strlen(name) + 1];

 for (int i = 0; i <= (int)strlen(name); i++)
 {
  m_name[i] = name[i];
 }
}

void Person::setAge(int age)
{
 m_age = age;
}

void Person::setSSN(string ssn)
{
 m_ssn = ssn;
}

string Person::getType() const
{
 return string("Person");
}

void Person::Write(ostream &os) const
{
 if (&os == &cout)
 {
  os << "Name: " << m_name << "\nAge: " << m_age << "\nSSN: " << m_ssn;
 }
 else
  os << m_name << "\n" << m_age << "\n" << m_ssn;
}

void Person::Read(istream &is)
{
 string name;
 if (&is == &cin)
 {
  cout << "Enter the Name: " << flush;
  getline(is, name);
  if (name.length() == 0)
   getline(is, name);
  cout << "Enter the Age: " << flush;
  is >> m_age;
  cout << "Enter the SSN: " << flush;
  getline(is, m_ssn);
  is.get();
 }
 else
 {
  getline(is, name);
  if (!is)
   return;
  if (name.length() == 0)
   getline(is, name);
  is >> m_age;
  getline(is, m_ssn);
  is.get();
 }
 delete[] m_name;
 m_name = new char[name.length() + 1];
 for (int i = 0; i < (int)name.length(); i++)
 {
  m_name[i] = name[i];
 }
 m_name[name.length()] = '\0';
}
```

I'm not even going to put in the inheriting class, which is Student, because I already get errors when I test out my Person class.

I've tried in my main the following:

```css
#include "Person.h"
#include "Student.h"

int main()
{

 Person ptr2Stu("Joe", 22, "123-45-6678");
 cout << ptr2Stu.getName() << endl;
 cout << ptr2Stu.getAge() << endl;
 cout << ptr2Stu.getSSN() << endl;
 cout << ptr2Stu.getType() << endl;

 system("pause");
}
```

I receive errors when trying to build this.

Comment: What errors do you get, and how much of this have you added since the last time the code worked perfectly?

Answer (score 1):

There is problem in `Person.cpp`

```
Person::Person(const char* name, int age, const string &ssn)
```

In header file, declaration is

```
Person(const char* const name, int age, const string &ssn);
                    ^^^^
```

So, change the either of the declaration/definition.

You can omit typecasts in `getSSN` and `getAge`.

Comment: Or you could change both the declaration and definition. Make the interface not cluttered with a `const` that changes nothing for the caller and make the definition enforce you not changing the parameter.